# How to perform an action conditional to several observables in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want to export a file containing a list of data when the user clicks a button. I have an observable (user$) which contains the user's identity. If the user is not authorised to get this data, they will be redirected to another page. If the user is indeed authorised, then the data is retrieved from the back-end and exported into a spreasheet (this part doesn't matter, I know how to do it). The title of the file depends on the identity of the user.

I am stuck at:

```
onClick(){
    this.user$.pipe(
      tap((user: User) => {
        if (!user.isAuthorised) {
          this.router.navigate(["/someOtherPage"]);
        } 
      }),
      switchMap((user: User) => {
        let myData$: Observable<Array<Data>> = 
          this.myDataService.getDataByUserName(user.name);
        this.exportService.exportFile(myData$, user.name);
      })
    );
}
```

The **exportFile(Array, string)** method needs the data to be exported as input, and it needs the name of the user to form the title of the spreasheet. How do I combine all these observables in a clean and efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picci is correct that you should return EMPTY so that observable is completed.  Also, in 99% of cases, I agree that you should only perform side effects inside of `tap` operator, so that it's clear a side effect is happening.

However, in this case the code is somewhat simple, so I think you can get away with the router navigation within a guard clause that returns `EMPTY`.  As for getting the `data` and the `user` in the same scope for you call to `exportService.exportFile()`, you can simply add a `.pipe()` onto your first call to `myDataService.getDataByUserName`:

```js
onClick() {
  this.user$.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
      if (!user.isAuthorised) {
        this.router.navigate(["/someOtherPage"]);
        return EMPTY;
      }

      return this.myDataService.getDataByUserName(user.name).pipe(
        switchMap(data => this.exportService.exportFile(data, user.name))
      );
    })
  ).subscribe();
}
```

---

It's sometimes handy to pass data from the view, to your controller methods.  If the view happens to have access to the current user, you could pass to your `onClick()` method.  This would simplify things a bit:

```js
onClick(user: User) {

  if(!user.isAuthorised) {
    this.router.navigate(["/someOtherPage"]);
    return;
  }

  this.myDataService.getDataByUserName(user.name).pipe(
    switchMap(data => this.exportService.exportFile(data, user.name))
  ).subscribe();
}
```

Here we don't need to subscribe to `user$` to get the user, since it's passed it.  This means we don't even involve observables at all when the user is not authorized.  In the case they are authorized, we only need a single `switchMap` since we only use 2 observables, instead of 3.

---

One last alternative, assuming the view model has the current user, is to put the conditional in the template, and break up your `onClick` method into to smaller methods: `downloadFile` and `goToOtherPage`:

```js
goToOtherPage() {
  this.router.navigate(["/someOtherPage"]);
}

downloadFile(user: User) {
  this.myDataService.getDataByUserName(user.name).pipe(
    switchMap(data => this.exportService.exportFile(data, user.name))
  ).subscribe();
}
```

```html
<button (click)="user.isAuthorised ? downloadFile(user) : goToOtherPage()"> 
  Download Data
</button>
```

Comment: Wonderful, that's even better.And it works!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem right, you need to concatenate 3 calls to some asynchronous services using the data returned by a service in the call of the following service.

If this understanding is correct, then I would proceed as follows

```
onClick(){
    this.user$.pipe(
      tap((user: User) => {
        if (!user.isAuthorised) {
          this.router.navigate(["/someOtherPage"]);
        } 
      }),
      // switchMap waits for the previous Observable to emit something
      // and, as soon as it emits, pass the control to the following Observable
      switchMap((user: User) => 
        // here you may want to check if the user is authorized (consider
        // that the tap operator used above is not stopping the stream
        // and therefore you enter this function even if you navigate
        // to another page - if the user is not authorized, then you
        // end the entire stream returning EMPY, which is an Observable
        // that does not do anything but completes immediately
        if (!user.isAuthorised) {
           return EMPTY
        }
        // the function passed to switchMap as parameter MUST return an Observable
        // in this case probably you want to return the Observable that 
        // retrieves the data for the user from the back end
        return this.myDataService.getDataByUserName(user.name).pipe(
           // the point here is that, for the following Observable, you
           // need both the data returned by getDataByUserName and the user
           // returned by this.user$
           // to do so you can pipe in a map operator like this
           map(dataForUserFromBackEnd => {
               return {user, dataForUserFromBackEnd }
           })
      }),
      // now you need another switchMap to pass the control to the final
      // Observable, the one returned by exportFile
      switchMap(({user, dataForUserFromBackEnd }) => {
          return this.exportService.exportFile(myData$, user.name);
      })
    );
}
```

Comment: If you not sure that you understand a question right, ask for details in the comment section first.

Comment: Your understanding is 100% correct, and thank you very much for such a detailed answer. Now, the issue is:my exportFile() method does not take in any Observables, only an Array<Data> and a string representing the user's profile. Therefore I cannot return it in the last switchmap. I have put the method in the last switchMap() and returned EMPTY instead, and it seems to work, but it doesn't always work. I'm guessing it's got something to do with my user$ Observable which is also retrieved from the back-end at the init of my component...

Answer (score -1):

You don't need `tap` operator. Just do everything in the `switchMap`. If user authorized return new observable, if not navigate to the page you mentioned and return `EMPTY`(or anything what is more convenient for you to handle). In case you have more observables to handle to open your file use more `switchMap` in the same `pipe`.